# Merging nodes in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am working with a database of interrelated notions, that I'd like to visualize in D3, but I would also like to let the users say, that for their search in this database some notions might be merged. For example "good visualization" and "nice visuals" could mean the same for them actually and would like to see their merged connections.

I would imagine them pulling one to the other, and then decide if I want to make it a parent, a child or a synonym. After the interaction the users would only want to see one node, with the aggregated connections of them both. Ideally I could store these user built connections to be able to offer for a next user as well.

Is there a solution already developed in D3 for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a feature like this in d3 AFAIK, but you could implement it.

When users indicate that something is a synonym or whatnot, you'd make the change at the model level (i.e in the underlying json/csv data), and then you'd rebind the modified data to re-render the visualization.

For the data persistence for subsequent users; you'd POST the modified bits to your server and store it in your DB.

These are patterns to follow regardless of whether you're using d3 or anything else.